# What are the contents in /sys/block when ubuntu is a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, filesystems, block-device

I am very confused to how `/dev/dm-1` was being used as a swapspace by my Ubuntu guest Virtualbox VM. `gparted` doesn't show these drives.
[image]

- What is going on here?
- How does the same drive `dm-1` have different permissions?
- Why can't I see /dev/ listed?
- Is there anything different in `/sys/block` when Ubuntu is a virtual machine?

[image]

Comment: I can do `cd /dev/`

Comment: I am very confused as to what is going on in this question. Different permissions to what? What happens when you `cd /dev`? virtual machine what? If you question is about the mode of the files in your second listing, then they are softlinks. softlinks always have that mode. It is not the mode of what is being pointed to.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Why are you telling us that?

Comment: Because OP says they can't but I can!

Comment: sorry, I fixed my question.